# How to reset panel look and feel in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, look-and-feel, uimanager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Panel losing color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425475/panel-losing-color)

When I click on the button that activates the file chooser, and add the resulting file the panel color disappears couse using uimanager to display file chooser as windows chooser.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.plaf.FileChooserUI;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class pan extends JPanel implements DropTargetListener {

    private DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    private JButton addbutton;
    private JButton removebutton;
    private JButton selectbutton;
    private JButton lockbutton;
    private JButton unlockbutton;

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public pan() {
        setLayout(null);
        addbutton = new JButton("New button");
        addbutton.setBounds(10, 10, 90, 100);
        addbutton.addActionListener(new Action());
        add(addbutton);

        removebutton = new JButton("New button");
        removebutton.setBounds(110, 10, 90, 100);
        add(removebutton);

        selectbutton = new JButton("New button");
        selectbutton.setBounds(210, 10, 90, 100);
        add(selectbutton);

        lockbutton = new JButton("New button");
        lockbutton.setBounds(310, 10, 90, 100);
        add(lockbutton);

        unlockbutton = new JButton("New button");
        unlockbutton.setBounds(410, 10, 90, 100);
        add(unlockbutton);

        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("New label");
        headerLabel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,
            Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.GRAY, null, null));
        headerLabel.setUI(new ModifLabelUI());
        headerLabel.setBounds(10, 120, 635, 30);
        add(headerLabel);   
    }


    class Action implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==addbutton){
                JFileChooser filechooser=new JFileChooser();
                filechooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);             
                try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager
            .getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

                filechooser.updateUI();
                filechooser.showOpenDialog(new pan());
                File files=filechooser.getSelectedFile();
                listModel.addElement(files);
        }       
    }
}
```

If you remove UImanger the problem gone

Answer (score 2):

Per [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) ... You might want to make sure the UI manager is first set to use the look and feel you want to use ...

**EDIT** For a concrete example @see [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762747/java-swing-writing-a-ui-that-will-repaint-itself-based-on-changes-to-a-custom)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
            // Set System L&F
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       // handle exception
    }

    new SwingApplication(); //Create and show the GUI.
}
```

Comment: your answer for other thing do you test code and see problem!!

Comment: @YaserHar I'm sorry? Was that a question?

Comment: dont worry test make frame and test code then call press add button and add any file then you will see panel color gone

Comment: how to make panel retrive its apperance and thanks

Comment: Also from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) referenced, It is possible to change the Look and Feel after startup by invoking `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);` on the component in question.